# Sitecore Lucene Search missing file inside Data\indexes\__system folder

Tags: lucene, sitecore, sitecore6

We are using Sitecore(Version 6.4) Lucene Search. When i am trying to search any keyword, it is throwing file not found exception. Lucene is looking for file _3zj.fnm inside Data\indexes__system\ folder.

I tried to rebuild search indexes from sitecore and since 4hours, it did not completed. Sitecore rebuild window is showing message saying "processed XXX items". This number has not changed since few hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of things you could try and eliminate first..

- **File locking** : Do you have a virus checker that could be locking the files and stopping them from being overwritten or possibly deleting them? Do you have anything enabled like DFS or drive sharing that could cause issues like this.
- **Permissions**: Do the `Data` and `indexes` folders have the correct permissions i.e. does the user the IIS worker process is running under (e.g. NETWORK SERVICE) have write and delete access to these folders.
- **Configuration** : Check that nothing has changed any of the lucene index definitions in the sitecore section of the web.config.

You are doing the right thing by rebuilding the index via the control panel but I would go into the `Data/indexes/__system` directory and delete everything in there before you do the rebuild just in case anything has corrupted something in the existing index. Depending on how many items you have the index shouldn't take very long at all, so if it hangs like that it normally indicates a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue with the "Rebuild the Search Index" hanging.
Sitecore was running in IIS 7 with .NET Framework v4.0 application pool running in Integrated Managed Pipeline Mode.
No errors in the Sitecore logs - just a note that says "Job started: RebuildSearchIndex".
The popup dialog just sat there with "Processing 0 items".

I noticed that the application pool in the target machine had one setting that was different from the default:

Load User Profile: False

Once I changed this to True, then the Rebuild could complete correctly.
And as Stephen mentioned, ensure that the Application Pool Identify (by default its NetworkService) has write access to your Data folder and delete everything in your \indexes directory to be sure.